Is ~np.zeros() is the fastest way to initiate a 1D numpy boolean array of Trues?
Trying to find the fastest method to initiate a 1D numpy array of True values.
%timeit -n 100000 -r 30 np.ones(10000, dtype=bool) returns 750 ns ± 35.7 ns
whereas
%timeit -n 100000 -r 30 ~np.zeros(10000, dtype=bool) returns 682 ns ± 7.47 ns
Behaviour probably depends on the array size but is there a general rule of thumb to which one to choose? Are there other faster methods?

If you want something fast, you should avoid creating a new array in the first place. This is what makes the operation expensive, not to mention Numpy internal overheads. Recycling them is the way to go.

Also creating a bit array (8-times smaller) can be faster though it is then generally less efficient to manipulate with Numpy directly (it depends of the kind of operation done on it).

The answer really depends on your OS and architecture. Fastest way on my machine is to keep around a reference array and do reference.copy() Only method that consistently measures in the nanosecond range (700-600 ns) on my machine. (while everything else is the order of 1-2 us). It's a lot less general purpose though.

np.frombuffer(bytearray().ljust(10000, b"\x01"), dtype=bool) is faster than empty or full. Benchmark results for NumPy 1.22.4:
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np' 'np.ones(10000, dtype=bool)'
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.12 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np' '~np.zeros(10000, dtype=bool)'
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.66 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np' 'np.full(10000, True)'
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.01 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np' 'a = np.empty(10000, dtype=bool); a[:] = True' 
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.25 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np' 'np.frombuffer(bytearray().ljust(10000, b"\x01"), dtype=bool)'
500000 loops, best of 5: 636 nsec per loop

This (ab)uses the fact that bytearray.ljust calls memset under the hood, which means that the bytearray can be initialized very quickly. The rest is just overhead from constructing the bytearray and the NumPy array.

There is a catch though: np.frombuffer results is a read-only array so it is probably useless for the OP.

@JérômeRichard yeah just caught that myself; bytearray() works and produces a properly r/w array, and is still faster than any other option.

This sort of crazy stuff is why I am here!

How about 2D numpy array? @nneonneo

@ruul: probably just make a bytearray and frombuffer of m*n size, then reshape. Reshape should be basically free if the data layout is compatible, although there will be a tiny bit of extra overhead so you should profile.

The following command seems to get better performance (no casting):
%timeit -n 100000 -r 30 np.full(10000, True)


On my machine, this is equally fast to np.ones(10000, dtype=bool) provided by the OP.

UPD: @nneonneo's solution is 2.5..3x faster than this
np.empty() then assign is faster
%timeit -n 100000 -r 30 np.ones(10000, dtype=bool)
7.06 µs ± 2.71 µs per loop

%timeit -n 100000 -r 30 ~np.zeros(10000, dtype=bool)
4.37 µs ± 1.8 µs per loop

%timeit -n 100000 -r 30 np.full(10000, True)
2.3 µs ± 668 ns per loop

%timeit -n 100000 -r 30 a=np.empty(10000, dtype=bool); a[:]=True
1.74 µs ± 672 ns per loop


This is crazy! I think this answer shows that np.full is currently sub-optimal and should be optimized. I will check its performance and improve its speed if I see anything wrong in the code :) .

I will be curious to see how my somewhat-silly bytearray solution benchmarks on your machine, seeing as the performance between np.ones and np.full is quite different (whereas it is not on my machine).

It takes 1.2 µs on my machine for the last while the former (and np.full) take 2.6 µs. The last solution of nneonneo is faster but also even crazier!

Note that the time to fill the L1 CPU cache is 0.09 µs. For the DRAM, it is >0.5 µs (probably 0.6-1.0 for 1 core). Here, the L1 cache should be used when doing the timings thousands of times (while DRAM should be used instead in a real-world code). Thus, most of the time should be spent in Numpy's overheads.

@nneonneo I'm testing in a default Google Colab runtime. I just checked the bytearray solution and can confirm it's 2.5..3 times faster than mine
